# A book where the main protagonists turn into a goblin and a pixie

Tags: story-identification, books

My father mentioned a book he read back in high school about two people (a girl and a boy) that were transported into a fantasy world. Either they were two teenagers/students, or two scientists that were lost, he's not sure. He mentioned that the longer the two stayed in this particular world, the more they began to change into two species of a fantasy race. The girl/woman began to turn into a pixie, and the boy/man began to turn into a goblin type creature.

The main thing that he says got a kick outta him was that the pixie dust, aka the thing that was always seen as magical in other stories, was pixie poop in this universe. A clever idea and joke in my opinion.

My father was born in the early 60's, so I imagine that if the book was new at the time, it would probably have been published in the late 70's/early 80's.

I know this is a shot in the dark, but does anybody happen to know of such a story?

Comment: My first thought is that this sounds like a Jack Chalker book, but I haven't found a match yet.

Comment: I think it could be The War of Fae series by Elle Casey. I haven't read the books, so I can't be sure, but the description seems to fit.
https://www.goodreads.com/series/76163-war-of-the-fae

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - The author suggests that it's more like sweat than poop; https://tiffanylovesbooks.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/character-interview-tim-the-pixie-war-of-the-fae/

Comment: Seems somewhat similar to the [River of Dancing Gods](https://www.amazon.com/River-Dancing-Gods-Jack-Chalker/dp/0345345010) by Jack Chalker, although the protagonists in that case were a male truck driver and a woman he was giving a ride to in his truck.